# Callback violates CSP policy even though it is referenced in 'script-src' policy

Tags: content-security-policy

Im getting a CSP violation in chrome console:

```
Refused to load the script 'https://ipinfo.io/?callback=jQuery....' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive
```

even though ipinfo.io is included the policy.

```
script-src 'self'  *.ipinfo.io;
```

Any ideas why ?
could it be because its a callback and not a static script ? could this be solved ?

[image: attached print screen]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

but you allowed only subdomains, not your main domain.

*.ipinfo.io  allows everything which is foobar.ipinfo.io but not the main Domain it self, you need to add it as well